# Bootstrap 5 column not working as expected with my design :(

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Working on bootstrap where I need to develop my footer exactly as below

[image]

Here is my part of HTML code

```
<footer class="footer">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 footer-Darkerblue">
        <div class="text-center">
            <ul class="footer-ul">
                <li class="footer-headtext text-uppercase">
                    destination
                </li>
                <li class="footer-Kilomet">
                    6.8 Kms
                </li>
                <li class="footer-min">
                    25 Min away
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 footer-Darkenblue">
        <ul class="footer-ul">
            <li>
                Status
            </li>
            <li>
                In Transit
            </li>                       
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Here is the [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/qzdvkvjr/)

Kindly please guide me where i am getting wrong i am not getting the exact output

Comment: you do have the 5 columns in the fiddle..then what is the problem?

Comment: @Lal the output if you see in fiddle it was not looking like the image the date column and the booking reference was not aligned

Comment: moreover the other text it was not looking exactly as per the VD design :(

Comment: Add padding around all the sub-sections apart from fixing your HTML

Answer (score 1):

Ok, took a look at your code, and saw that you had a few closing tags out of place.

You had:

```
<div class="footer-left-border"></div>
```

Simply move the closing tag to below your data.

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
  <div class="footer-left-border">
  <ul class="footer-ul">
    <li class="footer-headtext text-uppercase">
      DATE
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="footer-ul list-inline footer-text-date">
    <li>
      <em class="fa fa-calendar"></em> 25 Dec, 2015
    </li>
    <li>
      <em class="fa fa-clock-o"></em> 16:30
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle Fork](https://jsfiddle.net/v5cqg80j/) of your code, showing this.

Enjoy!

Comment: thanks for the reply but if you see the exact output my output was not same :(

Comment: well I tried. I at least succeeded in getting it to move up.  :)